# How to write sentences in an algorithm in latex?

Tags: formatting, algorithms, algorithmic

Hi I am trying to write an algorithm which looks something like the image below:

[image: Algorithm]

I was wondering how to write the "Step 1 (Update)" and also the rest of the line which says "When an edge e...." should all that be inside the math symbols i.e.. \[\] ??

I am kinda new to latex. Thanks for the help!

Also I was wondering what is the difference between algorithm and algorithmic?

Comment: See section 1 of the [algorithms bundle documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithms): `algorithm` is to `algorithmic` as `table` is to `tabular`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\smallarrowover[1]{\scalebox{.5}{$\overrightarrow{#1}$}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\underline{\sf Step 1 (Update):} When an edge $e=\{u,v\}\in E[G]$ arrives, update each $Z_{\smallarrowover{ab}}$ w.r.t.
\begin{equation}
Z_{\smallarrowover{ab}}(G)\leftarrow Z_{\smallarrowover{ab}}+\mathcal M_{\smallarrowover{ab}}(u,v)+\mathcal M_{\smallarrowover{ab}}(v,u).
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Initially I used `\vec{ab}` for the arrow over `ab`, but that did not stretch, and putting `\overrightarrow{ab}` in the subscripts did not make it smaller, as you want. So I defined a new command, which needs the `\graphicx` package. Also, you might not need the `\noindent` I have at the beginning, depending on what you have before it. I put it there so the whole thing would fit on one line.

P.S. I have no experience with the `algorithm` or `algorithmic` environments.

Comment: I think the OP was probably asking about the difference between the `algorithm` and `algorithmic` environments.

Comment: Yes, I meant the \begin{algorithm} and \begin{algorithmic} commands

Comment: Also when I try the above code I am getting: 'Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.109 ...ives, update each $Z_{\smallarrowover{ab}
                                                  }$ w.r.t. '

Comment: @Yathi what document class are you using, and which packages do you have loaded?

Comment: Hi.. This is the start of my report:
  
    \documentclass{acm_proc_article-sp}  
    \usepackage{amsmath}  
    \usepackage{algorithm}    
    \usepackage{graphicx}    
    \newcommand\smallarrowover[1]{\scalebox{.5}{\overrightarrow{#1}}}  
    \usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}  
    \begin{document}

Comment: @Yathi see my adjustments. Changing to `$\overrightarrow{#1}$` does the trick.